# Help to install the Ralink RT3070 wireless driver on Kali?

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux

I've downloaded latest Kali Linux (**amd64**) and installed it on VMware **Workstation 10**.

After installation I upgraded Kali's kernel headers to the latest version (now I have **v3.16**).

```
apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Now I want to install my **Alfa-AWUS036H wireless USB device** to Kali.

My device chipset is: **rt3070**. -> [ralink](http://www.ralinktech.com/en/) ([mediatek](http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/)) company.

I went to [MediaTek | RT3070](http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads/rt8070-rt3070-rt3370-rt3572-rt5370-rt5372-rt5572-usb-usb/) to download latest version of this chip.

When you check the extracted files of the downloaded driver you see many conditions for kernel 2.4 or 2.6 versions (meaning that it's an old driver and I think should change some code in that project).

Please help me step by step to install my wireless USB device on Kali.

I also found this thread with no help: [How do I install the Ralink RT3070 wireless driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148767/help-do-i-install-the-ralink-rt3070-wireless-driver)

When should I run this command (and why `rt5370sta` instead of `rt3070`):

```
modprobe rt5370sta
```

**What I did**

1. `apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
2. I went to this path `/os/linux/config.mk` and changed these lines:

   ```
   HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y   
   HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
   ```
3. I went to this file `/os/linux/rt_linux.c` and changed these lines:

   ```
   /* pOSFSInfo->fsuid = current_fsuid(); */
   /* pOSFSInfo->fsgid = current_fsgid(); */

   pOSFSInfo->fsuid = *(int *) & current_fsuid();
   pOSFSInfo->fsgid = *(int *) & current_fsgid();
   ```

   I did these changes because of some errors during the `make` command. Did I do that right?
4. `make`

   and its result:  http://textuploader.com/o49y
5. `make install`

   and its result :  http://textuploader.com/o49b

**My Problems:**

1. After updating Kali's kernel headers and connecting the USB device to Kali I have **ERROR for 802.11g WLAN usb wireless driver** and nothing happens.
2. After these commands

   ```
   make && make install
   ```

   a file is copied to `/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat`. Why `RT2870` instead of `RT3070`?

Also I had many warnings about unsigned variable and some errors during installation (**before step 3**) and because of those warnings and errors I did step 3 and after rebooting and connecting the USB device to Kali I still have **ERROR for 802.11g WLAN USB wireless driver** and nothing happens.

- Which parts of the driver's project should I change and how can I load the driver?
- Should I load driver manually, or after connecting does it load automatically?
- Should I use x86 OS and change my OS?

Comment: holly jesus christ. 
i find the solution. 
that was my usb driver... :)

Comment: Why and how did you determine that the chip set was RT3070..? Or was that a mistake and the chipset is actually RTL8187L or RTL8225?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your AWUS036H shouldnt be a ralink RT2870/RT3070 chipset. you got a cheap knock off the real AWUS036H uses the Realtek RTL8187 chipset

Comment: damn those people, yes it's a fake one...

Comment: Some fake AWUS036H also use a RTL8187, see [Original ALFA AWUS036H and Fake ALFA AWUS036H](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rXt98n2pcE), but yes some fakes also use the RALINK, see [The Difference Between Original and Fake Alfa AWUS036H USB Adapters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNylw_MAcWQ)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a fake one; it is simply a different chipset.  The would be like saying your Porsche is fake because it came with different tires.

Comment: The issue would seem to be whether RT3070 is the actual chipset in the OP's AWUS036H

Answer (score 0):

There are, in fact, *two* versions of the AWUS036H:

- Revision 1 uses RTL8187L
- Revision 2 uses RTL8225

Source: [DevWiki - ALFA Network AWUS036H](https://deviwiki.com/wiki/ALFA_Network_AWUS036H)